# how to use additional package in latex with react js

Tags: reactjs, latex

In Overleaf, we can use additonal packages in LaTex like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

When we use react-js to build a web site that can render the LaTex, how to make it work?

Comment: Are you using [react-latex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-latex)?